# How to Generate an Array in Google Sheets by splitting columns and duplicating rows

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, lambda

I have recently discovered the advanced Array formulas on Google Sheets (lambda, makearray, map etc). Yeah, I know, I am late to the party, but am very eager to learn how to use and understand these functions and no better way than to dive in with an advanced problem to practically apply the skills / knowledge....

### Question

Is it possible, using ***one*** arrayformula with lambdas and other array functions to dynamically generate an array by iteratively applying logic to duplicate and generate rows and cells given a basic input?

### Input

| Dimension 1 | Dimension 2 | Pages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Large | 1,2,3-5 |
| Blue | Small | 6,7,8-10 |

### Desired Output

| Dimension 1 | Dimension 2 | Page |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Large | 1 |
| Red | Large | 2 |
| Red | Large | 3 |
| Red | Large | 4 |
| Red | Large | 5 |
| Blue | Small | 6 |
| Blue | Small | 7 |
| Blue | Small | 8 |
| Blue | Small | 9 |
| Blue | Small | 10 |

---

### Logic

***1. Pages Field***

The "Pages" column of the *Input Table* needs to be split, based on the below logic:

- The value of "Pages" is a list of page numbers (similar to the format used when printing specific pages of a PDF document)
- First iteration: split by ","
- Next iteration: Split by "-"
- Final Iteration: Where there is a range of numbers, use *Sequence* formula to generate the sequential numbers (eg. 3-5 = 3,4,5)

***2. Other Dimensions Field***

- All other dimensions (ie. Dimension 1 and Dimension 2) will need to be duplicated accross the array generated above for the page numbers

### Interim Attempts

I have only managed to generate the page number sequence using the below formula (assuming *Input Data* is in cells A5:A6, but the formula below is only considering the "*Pages*" column...)

```
=tocol(lambda(z,map(CHOOSECOLS(z,1),CHOOSECOLS(z,2),lambda(x,y,sequence(1,y-x+1,x,1))))

(lambda(y,arrayformula(if(CHOOSECOLS(y,2)="",CHOOSECOLS(y,1),y)))

(LAMBDA(x,arrayformula(split(flatten(split(x,",")),"-")))(C5:C6))),1)
```

Any attempts to either include, append or merge in *Dimension 1 or 2* in the above output fails and I would like to know how to dynamically include these columns into the output?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78151275/using-regex-to-replace-multiple-instance-of-match-of-hypenated-numbers-into-comm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,arrayformula(split(tocol(A2:A&""&B2:B&""&map(C2:C,lambda(Ξ,if(Ξ="",,let(Δ,split(substitute(Ξ,"-",""),","),
       torow(reduce(,Δ,lambda(a,c,{a,let(Γ,--regexextract(c,"\d+"),if(regexmatch(c&"",""),sequence(1,(--regexextract(c,"(\d+)")-Γ)+1,Γ,1),c))})),1)))))),"")),
       filter(Σ,index(Σ,,3)<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful solution. I took the time to study the method you use and was not familiar at all to the functions used here, so worked my way through all of them one by one, took me a few hours to wrap my head around it all, but this was definitely a knowledge bomb. Thanks so much, great formula here...

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(rf,p, {IFERROR(BYROW(TOCOL(SPLIT(REPT("^"&BYROW(QUERY({rf}, " Select Col1, Col2 Where Col1 <> '' "), LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN("|",1,r))),
                                        BYROW(p, LAMBDA(c, COUNTA(SPLIT(c,",-"))))
                                   ),"^")), LAMBDA(r, SPLIT(r, "|")))),
 TOCOL(BYROW(p, LAMBDA(c, SPLIT(c,",-"))))})(A2:C,
 BYROW(QUERY({A2:C}, " Select Col3 where Col3 <> '' "),
       LAMBDA(rg, REGEXEXTRACT(rg, "(.+).-.")&TEXTJOIN(",",1,SEQUENCE(1,(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(rg, ".-.+"),"-(.+)\z")-
                                                                         REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(rg, ".-."),"."))+1,
                                                                         REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(rg, ".-."),"."),1))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Close, but not quite perfect. This solution only works with the examples shown in sample data of "Pages" field. It can not handle generic scenarios, eg: {1,2,3-5,12,15,17} or {15-20,25-30,31,33} etc.

Comment: I am getting the error: "Function MINUS parameter 1 expects number values. But '5,12,15,17' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number." on the rows that do not adhere to the same input as example

Answer (score 1):

I have been playing around with the basic idea of converting (e.g.) 3-5 into 3:5 and using row and indirect to generate a range of numbers like this:

```
iferror(--c,row(indirect(substitute(c,"-",":"))))
```

where c is one of the values obtained by splitting the string in column C by commas. Unfortunately it doesn't work as easily as as I had hoped because 3-5 is immediately seen as a date and 8:10 is immediately seen as a time.

Anyway this is the resulting formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(let(nrow,rows(tocol(A2:A,1)),range, A2:C,res,reduce({"","",""},sequence(1,nrow),lambda(aa,cc,vstack(aa,let(pp,REDUCE("",split(substitute(index(range,cc,3),"-","*"),","),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,iferror(--c,row(indirect(substitute(c,"*",":"))))))),{if(pp,index(range,cc,1)),if(pp,index(range,cc,2)),pp})))),filter(res,index(res,0,3)<>"")))
```

[image]