# Using regex to replace multiple instance of match of hypenated numbers into comma-separated sequences

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to convert string like this:

1,2,4-10,12,15-19.

I need to convert it to: 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,15,16,17,18,19

Supposed the string is in the cell A1, I got a little success using this formula:
`=regexreplace(A1;"(\d+\-\d+)+";join(",";sequence(value(regexextract(A1;"\-(\d+)"))-value(regexextract(A1;"(\d+)\-"))+1;1;value(regexextract(A1;"(\d+)\-")))))`

this formula yield me result: 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Please help to fix the formula, I'm new to regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ;split(substitute(A3;"-";"`");",");
join(",";tocol(map(Λ;lambda(Σ;if(regexmatch(Σ&"";"`");let(Δ;split(Σ;"`");x;index(Δ;;1);y;index(Δ;;2);sequence(y-x+1;1;x));Σ)));1;1)))
```

[image]

Comment: This work perfectly as needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

- Use `REDUCE` to iterate through the string
- Find the number of `-`s by (`REGEX`)`REPLAC`ing all characters that are not `-`( `[^-]`) with nothing and calculate the remaining `LEN`gth of the string. This is the number of times we need to iterate.
- In each iteration, we use `REGEXEXTRACT` using

  - regex `"(.*?,)([^,]+)-([^,]+)(.*$)"` to get
  - Capture group #1: `(.*?,)` - get `p`revious match ending with `,`, i.e., `1,2,`
  - Capture group #2: `(\d+)` - get `s`tarting `d`igit before the `-`, i.e., `4`
  - Literal `-`
  - Capture group #3: `(\d+)`- get `e`nding digit after the `-`, i.e., `10`
  - Capture group #4: `(.*$)` - get remaining  `s`u`f`ix until end of string `$`, i.e., `,12,15-19`
- Create the `SEQUENCE` of numbers between `s`tarting and `e`nding digit and `JOIN` the `p`refix and `s`u`f`fix.
- Repeat the above until all dashes are removed.

```
=REDUCE(
  A1,
  SEQUENCE(LEN(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^-]",))),
  LAMBDA(
    a,c,
    LET(
      res,REGEXEXTRACT(a,"(.*?,)(\d+)-(\d+)(.*$)"), 
      i, LAMBDA(i, INDEX(res,i)),
      p,i(1),
      s,i(2),
      e,i(3),
      sf,i(4), 
      p&JOIN(",",SEQUENCE(e-s+1,1,s))&sf
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just a little fun one reading 4-10 etc. as ranges A4:A10

```
=ArrayFormula(textjoin(",",true,reduce("",split(substitute(A1,"-",":a"),","),lambda(aa,cc,VSTACK(aa,ROW(indirect("A"&cc)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: I rem'er now that we dealt with similar scenario [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76082307/5479575) prior:>